# What is the ratio of standby crews to flying crews?

Tags: commercial-aviation, commercial-operations, crew, flight-schedules

Section 4.O of the [FedEx Collective Bargaining Agreement](http://fdx.alpa.org/portals/26/docs/2015_Contract/2015FDXCBA_web.html) discusses how pilots are to be compensated for being on standby. From what I can tell they basically get paid a "trip guarantee" that is close to the same as had they flown the leg, even though they may not get any flight time (right?).

That made me wonder: How many standby crews does an airline schedule for a given number of flights? Is it 1:10? 1:50? Does it differ between passenger airlines and cargo airlines?

Comment: Related : https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/25631/679

Comment: related: [What is a typical ratio of airline pilots to aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16780/3394)